# Returning Promises instead of data

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I've had a great deal of frustration lately when I was trying to use axios to fetch data from a localhost withing a React/Redux bookstore project.The reason why I used axios is to connect the App to a rails api(backend) and try to update the store from the DB whenever it is needed(namely the list of books). However, when I try to pass the response.data(array of books) of the api axios call to the Action Creator I get a Promise in the React component.

- Book List Component

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import Book from '../components/book';
import { removeBookAction, getBooksAction } from '../actions/index';

class BookList extends React.Component {


  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getBooks();
  }

  render() {
    const { books, handleRemoveBook } = this.props;
    console.log(books) // prints Promise {<resolved>: Array(12)} :(
    return (
      <tbody>
        {books.length > 0 ? books.map((book) => (
          <Book key={book.id} item={book} handleRemoval={handleRemoveBook} />
        ))
          : (
            <tr>
              <td>Empty List</td>
            </tr>
          )}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
}

const displayableBooks = (books, theFilter) => {
  //console.log(books)
  if (theFilter === 'All') {
    return books;
  }
  return books.filter(item => item.category === theFilter);
};

// inject store state as props to Booklist component
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    books: displayableBooks(state.books, state.filter),
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  handleRemoveBook: (book) => {
    dispatch(removeBookAction(book));
  },
  getBooks: () => axios.get('api/v1/books').then(response => {
    dispatch(getBooksAction(response.data));
  }),
});


BookList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList);

export default BookList;
```

- Books Action creators

```js
const creatBookAction = (book) => {
  return {
    type: 'CREATE_BOOK',
    book,
  }
};

const removeBookAction = (book) => ({
  type: 'REMOVE_BOOK',
  id: book.id,
});

const getBooksAction = (books) => {
  return {
    type: 'GET_BOOKS',
    books,
  };

}

const changeFilterAction = (filter) => ({
  type: 'CHANGE_FILTER',
  filter,
});

export { creatBookAction, removeBookAction, changeFilterAction, getBooksAction };
```

- Books Reducer

```js
const CREATE_BOOK = 'CREATE_BOOK';
const REMOVE_BOOK = 'REMOVE_BOOK';
const GET_BOOKS = 'GET_BOOKS';


const booksReducer = async (state = [], action) => {

  switch (action.type) {

    case CREATE_BOOK:
      return [
        ...state,
        { ...action.book },
      ];
    case REMOVE_BOOK:
      const index = state.findIndex((value) => value.id === action.id);
      return state.slice(0, index).concat(state.slice(index + 1));
    case GET_BOOKS:
      return action.books;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default booksReducer;
```

As you can see the code above, I am trying to create some sort of synchronization between the Redux store and the DB, but I am stuck at the fist step (i.e getting the data). I am a beginner with React/Redux and axios, so please consider explaining other alternatives if my approach (which is a combination of other approaches mentioned in tutorials) is inefficient of impossible to apply. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I realized that I made a grave mistake. The reason why I am getting a promise instead of the actual data is because of my books reducer. I made it an asynchronous function which I suppose will inevitably return a promise.

Comment: nicely catched :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a middleware to make async call action like redux thunk

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  handleRemoveBook: (book) => {
    dispatch(removeBookAction(book));
  },
  getBooks: () => dispatch(fetchBooksAction());
});
```

Here your async action

```
const fetchBooksAction = () => (dispatch) => {
  axios.get('api/v1/books').then(response => {
    dispatch(getBooksAction(response.data);
  });
}
```

Comment: but why does the books is said to be a promise? isnt the whole thing should fail?

Comment: on displayableBooks you have console.log(books) what does it's prints?

Comment: Hi @Gilad, The code that you provided doesn't solve my issue, it behaves exactly like mines. console.log(books) I use it to see what the component is getting after dispatching the actions(just for debugging).
PS: I am using "redux-thunk" thunk as a middleware when creating the store (as argument).

Comment: please print the response.data

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my browser's console : https://i.imgur.com/kWJqMrS.png